# Was Jack Kirby's later comic book art influenced by his work on concept art for Lord of Light?

Tags: lord-of-light, jack-kirby

As part of the attempt to rescue hostages from the U.S. embassy in Tehran (dramatized in the film *[Argo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024648/)*), Jack Kirby, "the king of comics," was hired to do some concept art for a fake film version of Zelazny's *[Lord of Light](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1611)*.  Many of the interesting sketches he made can be found online.

Yesterday, as I was answering [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174346/why-was-the-axe-in-justice-league-so-special-what-made-it-so/174579) question, it occurred to me that the Steppenwolf character from the 1980s (which I believe was redesigned based on Kirby's own ideas) was rather reminiscent of the god Agni from the novel.  His red color scheme resembles the god of fire, and the corded electro-axe is similar to the corded fire wand that Agni uses.  This set me wondering whether any of Kirby's later comic art was specifically influenced by the work he did on *Lord of Light*.  Is there any evidence of this kind of influence?